# How to use regular expressions in python?

Tags: python, regex

Hopefully someone can help, I'm trying to use a regular expression to extract something from a string that occurs after a pattern, but it's not working and I'm not sure why. The regex works fine in linux...

```
import re
s = "GeneID:5408878;gbkey=CDS;product=carboxynorspermidinedecarboxylase;protein_id=YP_001405731.1"
>>> x = re.search(r'(?<=protein_id=)[^;]*',s)
>>> print(x)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x000000000345B7E8>
```

Comment: If the leading GeneID were stripped out, you could create a dict of the key/value pairs and avoid using regular expressions. `dict(fragment.split("=") for fragment in s.split(';'))`

Comment: Did you read the documentation on how to use `re`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`.group()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group) on the search result to print the captured groups:

```
>>> print(x.group(0))
YP_001405731.1
```

---

As Martijn <s>has</s> had pointed out, you created a match object. The regular expression is correct. If it was wrong, `print(x)` would have printed `None`.

Comment: That's what I get for moving out of connectivity.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I gave you a mention :). I still respect you as a great pythonic master :D

Answer (score 4):

You should probably think about re-writing your regex so that you find all pairs so you don't have to muck around with specific groups and hard-coded look behinds...

```
import re
kv = dict(re.findall('(\w+)=([^;]+)', s))
# {'gbkey': 'CDS', 'product': 'carboxynorspermidinedecarboxylase', 'protein_id': 'YP_001405731.1'}
print kv['protein_id']
# YP_001405731.1
```